# AWS CodeDeploy. AppSpec: Script at specified location: scripts/start_server.sh is not executable

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-code-deploy

I have a porblem with the correct configuration of the AppSpec.yml. I'v been trying for hours now to get it to work correctly. The problem is that I cant get my ApplicationStart -script to run afterwards.

The logs file says that:

> Script at specified location: scripts/start_server.sh is not executable.  Trying to make it executable.

Which is pretty straightforward. My question is, can someone spot the mistake I'v been doing here? I want to give the scripts file 755 permission, so I can run it with ubuntu -user.

Here is what my AppSpec looks at the moment:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/app-folder
permissions:
  - object: /var/www/app-folder
    mode: 755
    owner: ubuntu
    type:
      - directory
  - object: /var/www/app-folder/scripts
    mode: 755
    owner: ubuntu
    type:
      - file
hooks:
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/start_server.sh
      timeout: 10
      runas: ubuntu
```

Comment: for testing purpose try giving 777 permission and check.

Comment: I tested that also, no changes :( The file is not even getting the 755 permissions specified

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my code-deploy agent was stuck on EC2 and only showing the last error before got stuck.

The error was:

> Script at specified location: scripts/start_server.sh is not
>   executable. Trying to make it executable.

Restarted the service and now working.